# BW-IBM Soap sometimes does not arrive at the application

Tags: java, soap, element

Hello I am having an SOAP app that does not make any sense. We use BW from IBM, we have the logs from the outcoming that shows elementFiveWithProblems being send, but in the application we dont receive the element **sometimes**, it come as 'null' sometimes we receive the content.
Someone has any ideia what can be the problem here?

```
<ns0:service_input xmlns:ns0="Bla_Bla_Schema.xsd">
    <Header>
        <ClientName/>
        <ClientRequestTime/>
        <ClientRequestID/>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <elementOne>1234567</elementOne>
        <elementTwo>5</elementTwo>
        <elementThree>BLA123456</elementThree>
        <elementFour>5</elementFour>
        <elementFiveWithProblems>003</elementFiveWithProblems>
        <elementSix>2</elementSix>
        <delayedReleaseID>SERVERNAME:1.2@swnode~EAI_BW@swnode~UUIJI123~45464646464/delayedReleaseID>
    </Body>
</ns0:service_input>
```

We only put logs to identify, and check the cases that works, what happens is that has nothing related.

Comment: Please attach more code/logs

Comment: I dont have any more logs, the logs from the BW are those that I send and in our application I simply get the INput and do a toString and dont see somethimes this element :( yeah, annoying